# Android save MediaStore image with mime type GIF

Tags: android, gif, android-gallery, mediastore

While this code successfully creates an image that is also present in the phone's gallery, the extension is '.jpg' instead of '.gif'.

```java
    File gifFile; // gif file stored in Context.getFilesDir()

    final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "Image" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/gif");

    // Create a new gif image using MediaStore
    final Uri gifContentUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    // Open a writable stream pointing to the new file created by MediaStore
    OutputStream outputStream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(gifContentUri, "w");
    // Copy the original file from the app private data folder to the file created by MediaStore
    IOUtils.copyFile(new FileInputStream(gifFile), outputStream);
```

Output file is created inside Pictures folder by MediaStore. If I manually change the output file's extension to gif, the gif animation is playing inside Android gallery.

I feel I'm missing a small detail for this to work

Comment: `"Image" + System.currentTimeMillis());` Does the `Image` come through in the Pictures directory? I tried `"Image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");` and `Image.gif` but all i get is `<milliseconds>.jpg`.

Comment: @blackapps Yes I get the same result as you, the image is saved into Pictures directory as <milliseconds>.jpg. I am not sure if that number is milliseconds or some other naming scheme that MediaStore uses.

Comment: It is the last modified time in milliseconds since ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed the DISPLAY_NAME line.

Add `contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image." + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");`

It goes to a subdir of the Pictures directory if the subdir exists `contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Mine/Image." + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");`.

For Android Q the DATA column is useless.

```
String displayName = "Image." + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif";
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
```

will do it there.

Comment: This works on HTC U Ultra (Android 8) with MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME and even without the MediaColumn.DATA. On Samsung A9 (Android 9) when using MediaColumn.DATA the image is saved as GIF into Pictures folder but opening with stock Gallery app says unsupported format :), Google Photos can open the GIF. The DISPLAY_NAME column can be used without issues.

Comment: On Android Q the MediaColumn.DATA seems ok to modify but not available for reading